# Why is the minimal polynomial of linear transformation $T$ the lcm of all elementary divisor

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Suppose you have a vector space $V$ over $K$ and you give $V$ a $K[x]$ module structure via a linear operator $T$. Why then is the minimal polynomial of $T$ necessarily the lowest common multiple of all the elementary divisors of $T$?

Comment: There are many ways to answer this question. It would help to specify what you don't understand. One answer is that it follows pretty straightforwardly from the fact that the minimal polynomial is the highest degree invariant factor.